# Clear the Screen Windows Phone 8/8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8

I cant seem to be able to find the way to clear the screen. I tried using Window.Current.Content = Null as suggested by a post (can't seem to find the link) but that doesn't seem to work.

I need the screen to remove all UI elements and add a single textblock with some content.

Comment: can you show some code of what you tried?

Comment: Sorry I scrapped the project. I tried it a few days ago.
Something along the lines of
    'Frame frame=Windows.Current.Content as Frame;'
    'frame=NULL;'
Again not too sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can call clear method of your layout element, and create textblock element from code e.g.,

**Xaml Code:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Name="stk">
        <Button Content="button 1"/>
        <Button Content="button 2"/>
        <Button Content="clear" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**C# Code:**

```
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        stk.Children.Clear();
        GC.Collect();

        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = "here is some dummy text";
        stk.Children.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out! I used a method to navigate it to a new page as a work around. I might use this code later though. 
Thanks again.